Aura closeQuickAction is not working for mobile version of Community Site
I want to get a QuickAction that will update record status without any modal window. I need to use Aura, because Aura Community Site supports only Aura Quick Actions, so I am writed aura component, that must be closed after init. Here is the code:
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>
    <aura:attribute name="sObjectName" type="String"/>
</aura:component>

And controller:
doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
    $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
}

That works well for desktop version, but when I open Quick Action in mobile it opens a modal in full window and doesn't close automatically.
Can this be fixed, or maybe there are other solutions to my problem?

A possible solution could involve handling the timing and the exact sequence in which events are fired. By adding a slight delay before firing the force:closeQuickAction event on mobile devices, the modal might have enough time to load and then close properly.
doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
    if ($A.get("$Browser.formFactor") === "PHONE") {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
        }, 300);
    } else {
        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
    }
    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
}

For me it works even with a 1ms delay, but I still don't like this solution. I hope someone will suggest a better one.
